# How can I share my Audio CD by DLNA in Ubuntu?

Tags: sound, cd, dlna

I have Ubuntu 20.04 on my PC to which is connected USB CD/DVD drive. I share some files trough SMB and DLNA (minidlna) to other devices in my network. For hard drives or even Data CD everything works fine, but I have a problem with Audio CD.

Is there any solution to share Audio CD by DLNA? I don't want to rip AudioCDs because I tested it and it's really slow. I want use my CD/DVD drive as input for every TV or Home Theater in my home. Can you help me?

Comment: What have you tried?  Maybe a link in the dlna music dir  to your CD mount point , and have wide_links=yes in your /etc/minidlna.conf file

Comment: @ubfan1 you can't mount AudioCD :( I tried it. I also mounted /dev/sr0 to some dir when drive hasn't any CD into, but it doesn't work either. Dir is empty.

Comment: Nothing in Ubuntu is going to help you by pass the CD security.